# How to accept any value that is not in the list?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, combobox, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In my Asp.net MVC project, I have a Kendo combobox that is attached to a list of customers in the model. I want the ability of inserting new customers (if they are not already in the list). I've combobox set up as:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
     .Name("CustomerName")
     .Filter("startswith")
     .Placeholder("Select a customer...")
     .BindTo(@Model.CustomerSelectList)
     .Events(e => { e.Select("onSelect"); })
     .DataTextField("Text")
     .DataValueField("Value")
     .Suggest(true)
     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:250px;" }))
```

I've also provided the onSelect() to make an ajax call to bring and fill up existing customer's addresses.

```
function onSelect(e) {
    // get the dataItem corresponding to the selectedIndex to get the text and value                
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());               
    var value = dataItem.Value;
    var text = dataItem.Text;
    //Retreive list for new selection
    var url = '@Url.Content("~/Request/GetCustomerAddress")' + '?CustID=' + value;
    $.ajax({ url: url, success: CustomerDataRetrieved, cache: false, error: AjaxError, type: 'GET', dataType: 'json' });
}

function CustomerDataRetrieved(data) {        
    $("#Address1").val(data.Address1);
    $("#Address2").val(data.Address2);
    $("#Address3").val(data.Address3);
    $("#City").val(data.City);
    $("#State").val(data.State);
    $("#PostalCode").val(data.PostalCode);
    $("#Country").val(data.Country);       
}
```

When I select an item from the existing customer list, it works well and fill up the customer's address. However, when I type a new customer name in the combobox, it clears the combobox automatically. How can I allow the Kendo combo box to retain the new value?

Update 1:
As you can see in the image below, When I type a value from the list the value comes into the combo box and pressing enter key after it takes me to the next field (Address1) with data filled in, and combobox value stays. However, if I type a new value and press enter, I move on to the next field (Address1), but the combobox value disappears.

[image: Combobox Behavior]

Comment: The question isn't clear. Is the onSelect method clearing the comboBox?

Comment: Yes. When the call returns from onSelect() - the combobox becomes empty. I've updated the question with screenshot and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
function onSelect(e) {

   // get the dataItem corresponding to the selectedIndex to get the text and value                
   var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index()); 

   // get the text value of the combobox
   var customerName = $('#CustomerName').data("kendoComboBox").text();

    if(dataItem ==! null && dataItem ==! undefined){          
        var value = dataItem.Value;
        var text = dataItem.Text;
        //Retreive list for new selection
        var url = '@Url.Content("~/Request/GetCustomerAddress")' + '?CustID=' + value;
        $.ajax({ url: url, success: CustomerDataRetrieved, cache: false, error: AjaxError, type: 'GET', dataType: 'json' });
    }

   // replace the text
   $('#CustomerName').data("kendoComboBox").value(customerName);
```

}

It might work with only wrapping the ajax call with the if, but if not try getting and replacing the value. My thought is that if you type something in it should not be in the datasource and the ajax lookup fails.

Comment: var customerName = $('#CustomerName').data("kendoComboBox").text(); returns nothing. customerName is  empty string i.e. "".

Comment: Didn't you just type something in there?

Comment: As I said, I type a new customer name in the combobox and press tab.